# Where I can request a new tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

While writing my previous question I realized that "Musical Practice and Performance" has a really low number of tags. I wanted to know how I can request the site administrators to suggest some new tags that to be added. I also cannot find a tag for this question too as it is a feature request.

So I am tagging some random tags.

Answer (score 4):

http://meta.music.stackexchange.com is the place for questions about this site.

You can create new tags yourself after you reach 150 reputation points. But tags come about *after* the question, not just to fill-in a vacant category. If you ***need*** a tag desperately for your question and cannot wait until 300, you can *flag* the question and ask that a moderator add the tag for you.

Go to https://music.stackexchange.com/privileges to check where you're at.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The reputation for beta version is 150. : )

Comment: Also make sure to read [the faq](http://music.stackexchange.com/faq)!

Answer (score 1):

I want to re-stress this: having a low number of tags is absolutely fine.

As @luser says - do not add tags for the sake of it. A problem on other sites is tag overload - and we need to regularly clean up and remove tags.

Comment: Unused tags are automatically deleted after 6 months.

Comment: Yep - but unused isn't the problem. Badly used is.

Comment: Tags can be used badly even if they are low in numbers.

Comment: Exactly - that is my point, Aura

Comment: @Aura, certainly true, but the the particular form of "badly used" that results in 1-2 questions per tag is harder to clean up.