# Please add more tags on "Musical Practice and Performance"

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where I can request a new tag?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/where-i-can-request-a-new-tag)

I tried to post a question on "Musical Practice and Performance" and I have found out that it is very short on tags. It's a feature request to add more tags on that site.

Comment: A tag can be added when the question needs it. If you feel a tag is missing for you question, but you don't have the rep to create one, ask your fellow users to do so.

Comment: Are there any tags in particular that you need?

Answer (score 2):

Since Music is a beta site, you can create tags yourself once you reach [150 reputation](https://music.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) (once out of beta, the rep required goes up to between 300 and 1500, depending on the site).

If your post could do with more tags, people that already have reached that level generally will retag your questions for you.

Comment: Since when was this bumped to 1500 from 500?

Comment: @Mysticial: on *meta* the rep is 500, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags.

Comment: When I joined SO, I swear that creating tags was 500. So unless I remembered wrong, it was increased sometime ago.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In fact, it's 150 rep for that site: http://music.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags

Comment: @Bart: already ahead of you. :-P

Comment: With an avatar like that I should have expected a ninja edit.

Comment: The privilege depends on what site you're on. On SO, it's 1500. On MSO it's 500. On graduated sites (including SF and SU) it's 300. On beta sites it's 150.